# Accessing data from data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have been trying to access the data and nested elements after the data attribute is itentified but I have no luck, here is the code:

```
 $('#item-prize-location').find('[data-region]').each(function(){


  //want to access data-region value
      //want to access nested divs with        

 });
```

when I do a console.log(this) is gives me all the nested elements but I dont know how to access them or the value of data-region.

Comment: can you specify what exactly you are trying to do?  please provide your html code as well as it is difficult to understand your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) property or jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$('#item-prize-location').find('[data-region]').each(function(){
      var region = this.dataset.region;
      // var region = $(this).data('region');
});
```

You can also use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method and store the values in an array.

```
var regions = $('#item-prize-location div[data-region]').map(function(){
      return this.dataset.region;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#item-prize-location').find('[data-region]').each(function(){

mydata=$(this).attr('data-region') //or mydata=$(this).data('region') 
//do stuff with mydata-- that is the data in the selected element
//for example:
console.log(mydata)
//You can access the element itself using `this` or $(this)


 });
```

`$.each` always returns the element. You need to re-access the data inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [**try fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WU27r/)

```
$('#item-prize-location').find('[data-region]').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).data('region'));       
});
```